# How to pair the most similar columns of two dataframes using greedy approach in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have got two dataframes of size 24x10 (actual df size is massive though). The pairing of all columns is required to be done in a greedy manner by enumerating the columns in df1 and finding the most similar (not necessarily exactly same) columns in df2. The result would end up producing pair of each column of df1 being paired with an unassigned column in df2. The dfs are as follows.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
   [2., 1., 1., 3., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
   [2., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
   [2., 1., 1., 3., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
   [2., 1., 1., 3., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
   [2., 1., 1., 4., 2., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [2., 4., 1., 4., 3., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [2., 4., 1., 4., 3., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [2., 4., 1., 5., 2., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
   [2., 4., 1., 6., 2., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
   [2., 4., 1., 5., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [2., 4., 1., 5., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
   [2., 4., 1., 5., 3., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 4., 1., 4., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 4., 2., 4., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 2., 3., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.]])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
   [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
   [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.]] )
```

The 'most similar' can be defined as the highest number of common elements between columns. Any help or clue deserves appreciation.
I tried what as follows.

```
for key1, value1 in df1.iteritems():
#print(value)
    for key2, value2 in df2.iteritems():
        common_elements = [e for e in list(value1) if e in list(value2)]
    l = len(common_elements)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more by what you mean by most similar? Is it the sum of the columns? Is it the values in the row per column? Provide an expected result and/or kindly elaborate on "most similar".

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: I wouldn't vote to close this question. As @Simon requested, give more information. It is a good and high quality question if you expounded it.

Comment: Should one column in df1 be paired only with 1 column in df2? For ex: columns 8 and 9 in df1 matches with column 4 in df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing the match.

Assumptions:

#1: If a column in df1 matches with column on df2, both columns are eliminated for further matches.
For example, if column 1 and column 3 in df1 is a perfect match for column 5 in df2, then only column 1 in df1 will be paired with column 5 in df2. Column 3 in df1 will need to look for new match.

#2: Both df1 and df2 will have same number of rows to compare. For this example, I am also considering rows and columns to be of same size. Minor tweaks to the code can address variance in columns but row counts MUST match.

#3: The column comparison has to be an exact match. In other words, if column 1 row 1 has a value of 1 in df1, then column 1 row 1 of df2 should be 1. If yes, matched on row & col. Data will NOT be rearranged to check for match in either df1 or df2.

With the above assumptions, the code is as shown below.

```
#create a list to store all the match counts
df_list = []

#iterate through df1 first
for cols1 in df1.columns:

    #convert df1 column value to a list
    x = df1[cols1].tolist()

    #iterate through df2 to match to df1 column data
    for cols2 in df2.columns:

        #convert df2 column value to a list
        y = df2[cols2].tolist()

        #iterate and compare each value in df1[col1] with df2[col2]
        #i==j will result in True or False
        #sum() will count all True values (i.e., all matched values)

        z = sum((i==j) for i,j in zip(x,y))

        #store match count, col 1, col 2 into the lsit
        df_list.append((z,cols1,cols2))

#once you have iterated through df2 for each df1
#sort the df_list by descending order of match count, ascending order of df1 column
#highest match will be first, then df1 column
df_list = sorted(df_list,key=lambda x:(-x[0],x[1]))

dfc1,dfc2,points = [],[],[]

#iterate thru df_list and pick only if df1 column and df2 column were not picked earlier
#dfc1, dfc2, points will store each matched pair

for p,c1,c2 in df_list:
    if (c1 not in dfc1) and (c2 not in dfc2):
        points.append(p)
        dfc1.append(c1)
        dfc2.append(c2)

#print the matched values

for i in range(len(dfc1)):
    print (f'{points[i]:2} rows of df1[{dfc1[i]}] matches with df2[{dfc2[i]}]')
```

The output for your input DataFrames df1 and df2 are:

```
24 rows of df1[7] matches with df2[3]
23 rows of df1[8] matches with df2[2]
20 rows of df1[5] matches with df2[4]
18 rows of df1[2] matches with df2[5]
17 rows of df1[6] matches with df2[9]
15 rows of df1[9] matches with df2[1]
12 rows of df1[1] matches with df2[6]
 9 rows of df1[4] matches with df2[7]
 5 rows of df1[0] matches with df2[8]
 1 rows of df1[3] matches with df2[0]
```

You can decide the cutoff (ex: consider matches > 15 or more). We can add the filter before we append the data into the list.

Comment: Can anyone show me how can I tweak the code if I consider the assumption #3 only?

Comment: You can sort the data in ascending order on both sides. then compare them for match. Let me add that code and share with you. In summary, I am going to sort `x` after `x = df1[cols1].tolist()` and sort `y` after `y = df2[cols2].tolist()`. Then do the compare. That way i am comparing values in the same order

Comment: But in my data, order matters. Rows refer to time steps so re-ordering the rows will affect my result I reckon. Actually, I want total number of actual intersection (row-wise) for all columns.

Comment: My solution already keeps row order. The solution ensures a match for rows. What do you want? Keep row intact or ignore row order?

Comment: Keep row intact

Comment: My solution already keeps row intact. What additional do you want? See the output as it shows the results match. Let me know if you need any tweaks to the code

Comment: I was trying to pose my problem in a different way, that requires more explicit explanations. Should I post it as a different question? Otherwise it would very lengthy comment.

Comment: setup a new question, explain the problem and I will try and answer it for you. Also just share the link here so I know where the new question is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66237443/pairing-columns-of-two-dataframes-iteratively-based-on-the-total-number-of-inter