# Pairing columns of two dataframes iteratively based on the total number of intersected values by greedy method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different dataframes which are as follows.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2., 1., 1., 3.],
                [2., 1., 1., 1.],
                [2., 1., 1., 0.],
                [2., 1., 1., 3.]])
df2 =  pd.DataFrame([[2., 0., 1., 1.],
                 [0., 1., 1., 1.],
                 [0., 0., 1., 1.],
                 [2., 2., 1., 1.]] )
```

My problem can be solved through the following steps.

Step1: we need to compute intersection (∩) of all column values in df1 with df2.

```
df1_c0_intersection_df2 = [[2∩2, 2∩0, 2∩1, 2∩1],
                       [2∩0, 2∩1, 2∩1, 2∩1],
                       [2∩0, 2∩0, 2∩1, 2∩1],
                       [2∩2, 2∩2, 2∩1, 2∩1]]
```

Step2: if intersection is null, then it is False and True otherwise, as follows.

```
df1_c0_intersection_df2_bool = [[True, False, False, False],
                            [False, False, False, False],
                            [False, False, False, False],
                            [True, True, False, False]]
```

Step3: then count total number of True in each column- list looks like as follows:

```
df1_c0_intersection_df2_bool_count = [2, 1, 0, 0]
```

The above list shows that the first column in df1 matches with the first column in df2 based on the highest intersection count score.

Step4: the first column from df1 and the first column in df2 will be opted out. Then will repeat the same for column 2 and so on.

```
df1_c1_intersection_df2 = [[1∩0, 1∩1, 1∩1],
                       [1∩1, 1∩1, 1∩1],
                       [1∩2, 1∩1, 1∩1]]

df1_c1_intersection_df2_bool = [[False, True, True],
                            [True, True, True],
                            [False, True, True]]

df1_c1_intersection_df2_bool_count = [1, 3, 3]
```

Then we will choose any one of them as there are two same scores. ANd so on...
Finally, it will return a list of all maximum values of of the boolean counts of the columns. For example, from above final_list = [max(df1_c0_intersection_df2_bool_count), max(df1_c1_intersection_df2_bool_count)] = [2, 3].

I tried as follows.

```
ints_list = []
for i in range(0, len(df1.T)):
for j in range(0, len(df2.T)):
    res = np.intersect1d(df1.iloc[:, :i].values, df2.iloc[:, :j].values)
    ints_list.append(res)
```

Comment: Do you want to compute df1 col1 with df2 col1 only or with all cols in df2? If so we will have 4 cols in df1 x 4 cols in df2 = 16 columns of True/False items. Correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. All columns in df1 with all columns in df2. Eventually we will get 16 columns (all combinations) of True and False.

Comment: There are some flaws in the way you are thinking about the steps. We can do step 1 and 2 easily. Step 1 will give a dataframe of 16 columns (if df1 = 4 cols; df2 = 4 cols). Step 2 is just a boolean set of the first one. So its easy too. Step 3 is just a count of Step 2. This will result in a 1x12 list (one row x 12 cols) where each col has a sum of all the True boolean values.

Comment: What I don't understand is Step 4. I assume we look at set 1 (cols 1 thru 4) that represent matches for df1 col1, Find the col that has highest number. That column would be representing df2 column. We exclude col 1 from df1 and the highest value col from df2. Then go to set 2 (cols 5 thru 8). Repeat this. Is that what you are trying to do? If so, how is this different from the solution I provided for your earlier post? Or are you always trying to match df1 col1 with df2 col1 only and not with any other?

Comment: if we compute boolean for all combination in step1 we do not require the step4.

Comment: see my results I just posted. Let me know what would you want to do in step 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you understand what I am talking, here's half the solution with steps 1 thru 3.

## DataFrame Setup / Initialization

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2., 1., 1., 3.],
                [2., 1., 1., 1.],
                [2., 1., 1., 0.],
                [2., 1., 1., 3.]])

df2 =  pd.DataFrame([[2., 0., 1., 1.],
                 [0., 1., 1., 1.],
                 [0., 0., 1., 1.],
                 [2., 2., 1., 1.]] )

print (df1)
print (df2)
```

df1:

```
     0    1    2    3
0  2.0  1.0  1.0  3.0
1  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  2.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
3  2.0  1.0  1.0  3.0
```

df2:

```
     0    1    2    3
0  2.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
1  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
3  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
```

## Step 1 & 2 : Create Intersection & Boolean DataFrame

Since I am iterating through the same DataFrames, I can do both at the same time.

```
df1_df2_l = {} #will store the key:val pair for df_list
df1_df2_b = {} #will store the key:val pair for df_bool
df1_df2_bool_count = []

for col1 in df1.columns:
    bool_counts = [] #to store bool counts for each df1 column

    c1 = df1[col1].tolist() #create the list of values for the df1 column
    for col2 in df2.columns:
        c2 = df2[col2].tolist() #create the list of values for the df2 column

        # do the intersection check per your requirement
        # If found, store the match, else NaN
        z_list = [x if x==y else np.NaN for x,y in zip(c1,c2)] 

        # do the intersection boolean check per your requirement
        # If found, store True else False

        z_bool = [x==y for x,y in zip(c1,c2)]

        #Now capture this information into the dictionary as key:val pair

        df1_df2_l[str(col1)+'_'+str(col2)] = z_list
        df1_df2_b[str(col1)+'_'+str(col2)] = z_bool

        #store bool_count for each column match with df2
        bool_counts.append(sum(z_bool))

    #store the bool counts for df1 column as a row in bool_count list
    df1_df2_bool_count.append(bool_counts)


#Now that you have this information, convert it into a dataframe

df1_df2_list = pd.DataFrame(df1_df2_l)
df1_df2_bool = pd.DataFrame(df1_df2_b)
```

The output of this will be as shown below:

Col Names:

0_0 = first col in df1 and first col in df2

1_3 = second col in df1 and fourth col in df2

**Step 1 Results:**

```
   0_0  0_1  0_2  0_3  1_0  1_1  1_2  ...  2_1  2_2  2_3  3_0  3_1  3_2  3_3
0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  ...  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  ...  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  ...  NaN  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
3  2.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  ...  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

**Step 2 Results:**

```
     0_0    0_1    0_2    0_3    1_0  ...   2_3    3_0    3_1    3_2    3_3
0   True  False  False  False  False  ...  True  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False  ...  True  False   True   True   True
2  False  False  False  False  False  ...  True   True   True  False  False
3   True   True  False  False  False  ...  True  False  False  False  False
```

## Step 3: Count of the values from df_bool

```
#print the bool counts
print (df1_df2_bool_count)

#You dont need to do the below part as we calculated the bool count already

#df1_df2_bool_count = [sum(df1_df2_bool[cols].tolist()) for cols in df1_df2_bool.columns]
#print (df1_df2_bool_count)
```

The output of this will be:

```
#new ask to store data per column
[[2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 4, 4], [0, 1, 4, 4], [1, 2, 1, 1]]

#older result without separating for each column
#[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 4, 0, 1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1]
```

Are you expecting a solution that says the following:

```
df1[0] matches best with df2[0] #since 2 is highest of 2, 1, 0, 0 (2 is in 1st (index 0) position)
df1[1] matches best with df2[2] #since 4 is highest of 0, 1, 4, 4 (4 is in 3rd (index 2) position)
df1[2] matches best with df2[3] #since 4 is highest of 0, 1, 4, 4 (4 is in 3rd (index 2) and 4th (index 3) position. We already picked 3rd, so we pick 4th (index 3)
df1[3] matches best with df2[1] #since 2 is highest of 1, 2, 1, 1 (2 is in 2nd (index 1) position)
```

These are the best matches we can find for each column in df1 against df2.

Comment: Can I get the output like this [[2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 4, 4], [0, 1, 4, 4], [1, 2, 1, 1]]

Comment: See updated code. I incorporated the code in step 1 & 2 itself instead of iterating thru the code again.